# How to move item in listBox up and down access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a list box contains 10 times . I have UP and Down buttons to move item up and down. My VBA works only if i set listbox multiselect property to 'None'. For the multiselect=simple option it throws error like in valid use of null in this line of code

```
     sText = lbfNames.Column(0, iIndex)
```

My VBA

```
    Private Sub cmdUP_Click() 
    Dim sText As String
       Dim iIndex As Integer
       iIndex = lbfNames.ListIndex
       'check: only proceed if there is a selected item
       If lbfNames.ListCount > 1 Then
         'index 0 is top item which can't be moved up!
        If iIndex <= 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Can not move the item up any higher.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' If iIndex = -1 Or lbfNames.ListCount > 1 Then
        'save items text and items indexvalue
        sText = lbfNames.Column(0, iIndex)
        lbfNames.RemoveItem iIndex
        'place item back on new position
        lbfNames.AddItem sText, iIndex - 1
        'if you keep that item selected
        'you can keep moving it by pressing cmdUp
        lbfNames.Selected(iIndex - 1) = True
        iIndex = iIndex - 1
   End If
   End sub
```

And i was trying to convert the below C# code(found in stackoverflow) to Access VBA throwing errors. Some data members not found.

```
     public void MoveUp()
 {
     MoveItem(-1);
 }

 public void MoveDown()
 {
    MoveItem(1);
 }

 public void MoveItem(int direction)
 {
    // Checking selected item
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null || listBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
        return; // No selected item - nothing to do

    // Calculate new index using move direction
    int newIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + direction;

    // Checking bounds of the range
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= listBox1.Items.Count)
        return; // Index out of range - nothing to do

    object selected = listBox1.SelectedItem;

    // Removing removable element
    listBox1.Items.Remove(selected);
    // Insert it in new position
    listBox1.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);
    // Restore selection
    listBox1.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
}
```

Is there anyway to do this in access vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually reconstructed this setting but could never get the error you mentioned. I did play around with the code to adjust it to what you were trying to do. Try this:

```
Private Sub cmdup_Click()
Dim sText As String
Dim iIndex As Variant
Dim selection() As Integer
Dim n, topSelection As Integer

' save the indexes of the selected items,
' they will be deselected after the first removal
For Each iIndex In lbfnames.ItemsSelected
    ReDim Preserve selection(0 To n)
    selection(n) = iIndex
    n = n + 1
Next

'loop through all the selected indexes
'this will also ensure you will only proceed if there is a selected item
For n = LBound(selection) To UBound(selection)
    'save items text and items indexvalue
    sText = lbfnames.Column(0, selection(n))

    If selection(n) <= topSelection Then 'index topSelection is top item which can't be moved up!
        MsgBox ("Can not move item '" & sText & "' up any higher.")
        topSelection = topSelection + 1
    Else
        'first remove item from old position
        lbfnames.RemoveItem selection(n)
        'place item back on new position
        lbfnames.AddItem sText, selection(n) - 1
        'change the index of the selected value to the new index (for reselection)
        selection(n) = selection(n) - 1
    End If
Next
'loop through the selection again to reselect
For n = LBound(selection) To UBound(selection)
    lbfnames.Selected(selection(n)) = True
Next
End Sub
```

The code and comments are self-explanatory I think, but here is a quick run-through:

1. I save the selected elements indexes first because I noticed
   after the removal/addition of the element that the selection was
   gone.
2. I then run through this selection, I reused your code here.
   Changed the condition for the pop up message, because if you select
   the top 2 elements for example (say 1 and 2), you don't want to only
   get the messagebox for 1 and then in the next loop put 2 ahead of 1.
   (Unless that is what you want, then change this condition back to 0)
3. Add the end I loop through the selected elements a second time to select them again for moving them further up the list.

Note: the example C# code shows a more generic function for both directions of movement. I did not adapt that, I think that is a good idea but leave it to you to implement (always a good exercise to understand the code).

Comment: Works perfect!!Thank you so much. For item moving down do i need to change the code in *Else* part?

Comment: @sam Yes indeed, the code in the Else part as well as the topSelection variable (because now the item on the bottom is the limit). Easiest is to try to adjust the function for moving down and when it works compare with this one and see how you can combine them into one more generic function (like your C# example). Try it out, play around and just ask a new question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want the wrap around feature modify the above solution to this ..

```
Option Explicit
Private Enum directions
    down = -1
    up = 1
End Enum

Private Sub cmdDown_Click()
    moveListItem (down)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMvUp_Click()
    moveListItem (up)
End Sub

Private Sub moveListItem(direction As directions)
    With Me.ListBox1
        Select Case .ListIndex
            ' at bottom and moving down then wrap around to top
        Case Is >= .ListCount + direction

            ' at top and moving up then wrap around to bottom
        Case Is < direction

        Case Else
            .AddItem .Column(0, .ListIndex - direction), .ListIndex + ((direction + 1) / 2)
            .RemoveItem (.ListIndex - direction)
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is type safe for direction by using an enum.
The solution allows movement up and down the list.
The solution wraps the movement (e.g. if at top of list and attempting to move up it wraps the item to the bottom.

```
Private Enum directions
    down = -1
    up = 1
End Enum

Private Sub cmdDown_Click()
    moveListItem (down)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMvUp_Click()
    moveListItem (up)
End Sub

Private Sub moveListItem(direction As directions)
    With Me.ListBox1
        Select Case .ListIndex

            ' at bottom and moving down then wrap around to top
        Case Is >= .ListCount + direction
            .AddItem .Column(0, .ListCount - 1), 0
            .RemoveItem (.ListCount - 1)
            .Selected(0) = True

            ' at top and moving up then wrap around to bottom
        Case Is < direction
            .AddItem .Column(0, 0), .ListCount
            .RemoveItem (0)
            .Selected(.ListCount - 1) = True

        Case Else
            .AddItem .Column(0, .ListIndex - direction), .ListIndex + ((direction + 1) / 2)
            .RemoveItem (.ListIndex - direction)
        End Select

    End With
End Sub
```